# How to build a simple offline form submission app?

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, local-storage

I'm a Webdev beginner, have been learning some Python/PHP/Javascript and want to help a friend of mine with a project.

She's conducting a large scale survey of old houses/windows, and fills in forms (similar to Google Forms). However, she doesnt always have 3G coverage on her phone, so she wants some way of uploading the data when she gets online, and she wants to be able to upload photos and attach these to the forms.

I've found a [javascript-library](http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2010/12/18/using-html5-localstorage-as-a-fallback-for-offline-form-submission/) which makes use of html5 localstorage, but I havent understood if localstorage also accepts file uploads? Also, when you have submitted one form you would need internet access to open up the form again to submit another form.

Are there libraries or projects around that would help me with some of this, so I dont have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Take a look at parse.com.  The PFObject class has a method called `saveEventually` that will cache the save until it is on line.  Be aware, however, there is a finite cache size (currently documented to be 10MB) that will purge older save requests when the cache hits its size limit.

Comment: Use search terms `ios android "store and forward"` for various frameworks and solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be very difficult to do with a web app. Your going to have to rely on something like AJAX to send the data and if it times out store in local storage and keep retrying every few minutes, because a web app has no access to anything like checking the wifi status etc.

Also that there is a limit to the size you can use in html5 local storage:
[What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)
, this is not going to work if you want to hold onto photos.

This would require a native or minimum a hybrid app (like phonegap) to store the data on the actual device in a file or SQLite database. This way you can store what you like, have access to the status of the internet connection and even have prompts to appear on the screen (when the app is in the background) to remind her that there are still some that need to be uploaded.

It will be much more reliable and stable this way

Comment: PhoneGap seems to be a winner. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem, phonegap would be quite suited for this type of application where its mostly just a html form but you need some low level support. I wouldn't use it for much more than that however, not really a fan

Answer (score 1):

You can create an app which stores the data (form) in the Local DB (ie SQLite) of the App.

Once she is online (mostly wifi) she can start uploading the data.

Comment: @MarcusAdams But to save data in SQLiteDb is a better option to save data

Comment: I'm guessing that for this purpose, SQLLite is overkill. User doesn't need to query the data or store data for more than one user or survey.